# How to release shape object variable or reset it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which trigger automatically give number to shape in range of cells.

```
Sub numShape()

Dim masqueA As Range
Dim cpt As Integer
Dim shapeTemp As shape
Set masqueA = Range("b33:l42")
cpt = 1

For Each shapeTemp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(masqueA, shapeTemp.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
        shapeTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = cpt
        cpt = cpt + 1
    End If

Next shapeTemp
End Sub
```

I loop through all shapes of my sheet and if they are in `masqueA` range I give them growing numbers (1,2,3....). It does what I want.
However if I move one shape of its position, for exemple I swap shape numbered 1 with another one numbered 2, and re-trigger the above code, the shapes keep their initial number. Which make shape numbered 1 placed after the one numbered 2.
I tried differents way to reset shapes, through the same loop than above :

```
shapeTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = ""
```

or

```
shapeTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = vbNullString
```

It put shapes text to null but when I re execute `Sub numShape()` I still have the same problem. So I tried to release variable object memory with :

```
Set shapeTemp = Nothing
```

Still same issue.

So my questions are :
- How shape object manages text ?
- Is my original way to set text to shapes causes this issue ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is not that the text of the shape cannot be modified - it is modified every time you call your routine. You are simply assigning them the same text again and again.

The reason is that the `Shapes`-collection returns the shapes of a worksheet in the order of creation, not of their position.

The following code loops over all cells of your range (from top to bottom and left to right), checking if the shape starts within the cell and gives it the next number.

```
Sub numShape()

    Dim masqueA As Range
    Dim cpt As Integer
    Set masqueA = Range("B33:L42")
    cpt = 1

    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    For row = 1 To masqueA.Rows.Count
        For col = 1 To masqueA.Columns.Count

            Dim shapeTemp As Shape
            For Each shapeTemp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                If Not Intersect(masqueA.Cells(row, col), shapeTemp.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
                    shapeTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = cpt
                    cpt = cpt + 1
                End If
            Next shapeTemp
        Next col
    Next row

End Sub
```

Exchange the for-loops for `col` and `row` if you want to sort from left to right.

Comment: I see, I was looping over all shapes of the sheet, so as you said in order of their creation. But as you lopp over cells you're able to go in order of shapes position. It makes sens when you explain it. It seems so easy when you say it.